# MySQL: How to achieve multiple conditions in CASE WHEN THEN

Tags: mysql, case

I have below query:

```
SELECT users_name, first_name, last_name,
(CASE
    WHEN flag1==1 AND flag2==1 AND flag3==0 THEN 'Active'
    WHEN flag1==0 AND flag2==1 AND flag3==0 THEN 'Deactive'
    WHEN flag1==0 AND flag2==0 AND flag3==0 THEN 'Disabled'
    ELSE ''
END) as Status FROM `users`
```

I have multiple flag conditions before defining it's status but on running the above query it gives me.

```
Syntax error near==1
```

What's  the correct way to achieve it?

**Intended Result:**
**username|firstname|lastname|status**
     Alex      |    Alex     |   mark     |  Active
     April      |    April    |   mark     |  Deactive

Comment: The null safe equal operator in mysql is <=> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't store n flags. I might instead store BITWISE integers; 3 for active, 2 for deactive, 0 for disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL the comparision operator is  `=` so  use `=`  (and not  `==`  ):

```
SELECT users_name, first_name, last_name,
(CASE
    WHEN flag1 = 1 AND flag2 = 1 AND flag3 = 0 THEN 'Active'
    WHEN flag1 = 0 AND flag2 = 1 AND flag3 = 0 THEN 'Deactive'
    WHEN flag1 = 0 AND flag2 = 0 AND flag3 = 0 THEN 'Disabled'
    ELSE ''
END) as Status FROM `users`
```